# Can't splice away a subarray

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, splice

I want to flatten two arrays in a subarray, replace the one after the current counter with the result and remove the current counter subarray. For some reason, splice is not working for me; I get the error: arg.splice() is not a function.
Can anyone explain why?

```
function sym(args) {
  var arg = arguments;
  for (var i = 0; i < arg.length; i++) {    
    if (arg[i+1]) {
      arg[i+1] = flatten(arg[i], arg[i+1]);
      arg.splice(i,1);
    }
  }


  function flatten(arr1, arr2) {
    return [arr1, arr2].reduce(
    function(a,b){
      return a.concat(b);
    }, []);
  }
}

sym([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4]);
```

Comment: `arguments` is not an array, it's an "array-like" object.  You need to "convert" it into an array.  `var arg = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, forgot I have to convert arguments into a proper array first. Stupid me.

Comment: @gyre I believe you have to wait a day to do that.